# docker multiple sites

Tags: docker

У меня на локалке около 5 сайтов, у каждого есть свой докер контейнер (LEMP stack).  И везде стоит вывод на 80 порт. Соответсвенно каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь одновременно запустить 2 локалки, возникает ошибка. Как альтернатива, у меня есть docker-compose со всеми сайтам в 1 файле, чтобы можно было запустить сразу все. Но так не дело. Мне нужно, чтобы человек, который получил от меня сайт, мог его запустить, а получив второй, без танцев с бубном запустить и его, не вырубая первый.

Мое решение - не использовать 80 порт. Но тогда возникает проблема с локальными хост именами. То есть я могу зайти на 127.0.0.1:81, но не могу зайти на test.loc (который в hosts так и прописан, как 127.0.0.1:81)

Как это делают другие люди вообще? Подскажите правильное решение. И, может быть, возможно сделать так, чтобы из коробки настраивался красивый хост на локалке еще?

UPD -
Вот такая картинка примерно в docker-compose:

```
   version: '3.7'
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: trion_nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./:/var/www/html/trion
            - ./docker/logs:/var/log/nginx
        depends_on:
            - php
            - pgsql
        links:
            - php
    php:
        container_name: trion_php
        build: ./docker/images/php         
        image: trion_php
        links:
            - pgsql
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html/trion
    pgsql:
        container_name: trion_pgsql
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - PGDATA=/tmp
        ports:
            - 5434:5432
        volumes:
            - ./docker/postgres/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
     pgdata:
```

Comment: Другие люди ставят nginx на 80 порт, настраивают в нём нужное количество виртуальных хостов и делают proxy_pass на нужные порты для каждого сайта

Comment: В LEMP stack есть же Nginx? Используйте его для проксирования хостов, как сказал @andreymal. Мануалов на эту тему полно.

Comment: @dmtr у меня однозначно недостаточно знаний про проксирование хостов, можно, пожалуйста вкратце описать? либо пример какой нибудь? никогда так не делал

Comment: Опишите концепцию, как вы хотите, чтобы работало, а мы уже подскажем вам. @PaulWall

Comment: @dmtr нужно, чтобы другой человек, мог тыкнуть docker-compose внутри сайта и он заработал по красивому пути типа test.loc и затем если у него есть еще 1 сайт то он мог точно также запустить на test2.loc при этом критично, чтобы оба работали одновременно. ну и хоть 100 сайтов по такой лоигке

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, у каждого приложения внутри поднятого docker compose на локальном IP разные порты. Допустим, 81, 82 и т.д... Исходя из этого, предлагаю следующее решение.

1) Создаете для каждого приложения конфигурации хостов, например app1.conf, app2.conf и им подобные.

**app*.conf:**

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name test.local;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://local_ip:port
   }
}
```

2) В каждом конфиге меняете порт на локальный порт, на котором висит приложение.

3) Конфиги кладете в `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*`

4) Перезапускаете Nginx.

Если что, по мере вопросов, ответ будет дополнен.

Comment: а разве для этой схемы не нужен локально установленный nginx?

Comment: обновил вопрос чуток, у меня в докере 80 порт берется и отправляется на 80 на реальной машине, соответсвенно больше 1 Nginx контейнера не запустится никогда

Comment: если он у вас есть внутри `LEMP stack`, то можете использовать его, если нет, можете поднять его в докере, можете поставить локально, не имеет значения. Указание портов `"80:80"` для работы с Nginx из внешней сети и внутренней. На мою предложенную схему не влияет.

Comment: - "80:80" а как с этим быть? как может не влиять? я может не понимаю чего-то

Comment: Оставьте этот вопрос на потом, в текущей ситуации не влияет. Главное не убирайте эти порты из docker-compose.yml

Comment: вы правильно поняли, что у меня много docker-compose файлов? и в каждом 80:80

Comment: Вы можете из них убрать nginx и запустить его одним отдельным контейнером

Comment: А приведите полный docker-compose файл

Comment: обновил в вопросе. И нет, я не могу убрать nginx оттуда, мне нужно, чтобы человек мог запустить все сразу, только через docker-compose не устанавливая ничего более вообще, соответственно я не могу выпиливать nginx из контейнеров

Comment: Не рассматриваете вариант запустить все приложения в одном потоке?

Comment: дак это уже есть, и мне это не подходит совершенно, тк я же не знаю какие нужно запустить будет одновременно

Comment: я подумаю и дам вам ответ, если меня не опередят